Flutter: Android System Back Button Exits Application Instead of Popping Page
I'm developing a Flutter application and encountering an issue with the Android system back button. When I try to navigate back using the Android system back button, instead of popping the current page and returning to the previous one, the application exits. I am expecting that I when I use the system navigation on Android it would pop the payment settings screen back to the settings screen instead of just exit the whole application.
My flutter version for the project: 3.19.6
Dart version: Dart 3.3.4
settings.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:example/theme/theme.dart';
import 'package:example/widgets/app_drawer.dart';

class Settings extends StatelessWidget {
  const Settings({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: AppTheme.lightTheme.hintColor,
        title: Text(
          'Settings',
          style: AppTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.displayMedium!
              .copyWith(color: Colors.white),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      drawer: const AppDrawer(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            height: size.height,
            width: size.width,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: AppTheme.lightTheme.hintColor,
            ),
            child: Container(
              height: size.height,
              width: size.width,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                  topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                ),
                color: AppTheme.lightTheme.dialogBackgroundColor,
              ),
              child: Align(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 30, top: 30),
                      child: Text(
                        'Preference',
                        style: AppTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.headlineLarge!
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: OptionListItem(context, 'Appearance', '/home'),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: AppTheme.lightTheme.dividerColor,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: OptionListItem(context, 'Notifications', '/home'),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: AppTheme.lightTheme.dividerColor,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: OptionListItem(context, 'Accessibility', '/home'),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: AppTheme.lightTheme.dividerColor,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: OptionListItem(context, 'Language', '/home'),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: AppTheme.lightTheme.dividerColor,
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: Text(
                        'Payments',
                        style: AppTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.headlineLarge!
                            .copyWith(fontSize: 18),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                      ),
                    ),
                    const SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 30),
                      child: OptionListItem(
                          context, 'Payment Settings', '/payment_settings'),
                    ),
                    Divider(
                      thickness: 0.5,
                      color: AppTheme.lightTheme.dividerColor,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget OptionListItem(BuildContext context, String label, String path) {
    return GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => GoRouter.of(context).push(path),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
          child: Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            height: 20,
            child: Text(
              label,
              style: AppTheme.lightTheme.textTheme.displaySmall!
                  .copyWith(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}


payment_settings.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:example/widgets/app_appbar.dart';

class PaymentSettings extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaymentSettings({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      appBar: AppAppbar(
        title: 'Payment Settings',
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text('This is the payment settings page.'),
      ),
    );
  }
}


routes.dart
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:example/page/home_screen.dart';
import 'package:example/page/payment_settings_page.dart';
import 'package:example/page/settings_screen.dart';


class AppRoute {
  GoRouter route = GoRouter(
    initialLocation: '/home',
    routes: <RouteBase>[
      GoRoute(
        path: '/',
        builder: (context, state) => const Home(),
      ),
      GoRoute(
        path: '/home',
        builder: (context, state) => const Home(),
      ),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/settings',
        builder: (context, state) => const Settings(),
      ),

      GoRoute(
        path: '/payment_settings',
        builder: (context, state) => const PaymentSettings(),
      ),


    ],
  );
}


I have tried searching solutions online and I've noticed that there are some people saying that this is the GoRouter's problem. But I really need GoRouter for my project is there any solution that can help me solve this issue?
This is the post I have came across
(https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/140869)

I have tried your code and it's working perfectly fine as you want. It doesn't exits when system navigation's back button used. Remove Invalidate Caches and try again.

The GitHub issue link you shared suggests downgrading go_router to v12 to fix the issue.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:example/widgets/app_appbar.dart';

class PaymentSettings extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaymentSettings({super.key});

  @overridee
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Settings(),
          ),
        );
        return  true;
      },

      child: const Scaffold(
        appBar: AppAppbar(
          title: 'Payment Settings',
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Text('This is the payment settings page.'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

